# What are the binding properties of post-quantum KEMs?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, key-exchange, kem

Performing a key exchange with post-quantum KEMs is [very different](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/271) to ECDH, which will likely cause vulnerabilities in protocols during the migration to post-quantum cryptography.

One example is that different KEMs can have different [binding properties](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/1933), leading to [re-encapsulation attacks](https://cryspen.com/post/pqxdh/) if you're not careful.

Some [less formal guidance](https://durumcrustulum.com/2024/02/24/how-to-hold-kems/) is starting to come out about this, but I've not seen anything on this site about this topic. It would be good to get a developer friendly summary of the different types of binding properties, when they matter, how you achieve them, and which NIST [finalist](https://csrc.nist.gov/pubs/fips/203/ipd)/[Round 4](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/post-quantum-cryptography/round-4-submissions) KEMs do and do not provide such properties by default.